# Mapping Odd relationship in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relationships

I have a set of 3 models, which is an odd many-to-many-ish relationship.

```
public class Metric {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class ActionPlan {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    //...

    public virtual ICollection<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }
}

public class PlanMetric {
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public int MetricId { get; set; }
    public decimal GoalValue { get; set; }

    public virtual ActionPlan Plan { get; set; }
    public virtual Metric Metric { get; set; }
}
```

I have the relationships mapped as follows:

```
public class PlanMetricMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<PlanMetric> {
    public PlanMetricMapping() {
        ToTable("PlanMetric");

        HasKey(m => new {
            m.MetricId,
            m.PlanId
        });

        Property(m => m.GoalValue)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasPrecision(10, 2);

        HasRequired(m => m.Metric)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.MetricId);

        HasRequired(m => m.Plan)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.PlanId);
    }
}

public class ActionPlanMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<ActionPlan> {
    public ActionPlanMapping() {
        ToTable("ActionPlan");

        HasKey(m => m.Id);

        // ...

        //HasMany(m=>m.Metrics) // how do I get to this data?
    }
}
```

The problem is

1) EF is creating an `ActionPlan_Id` field in my `Metric` table, and I'm not sure why.

2) I don't know how to set up my mapping to be able to navigation from a `Plan` to it's `Metrics`.

Comment: why did you put `public virtual ICollection<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }` in `ActionPlan`?

Answer (score 0):

EF is creating an `ActionPlan_Id` field because you have

```
public virtual ICollection<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }
```

in your `ActionPlan` definition, which EF interprets as a one-to-many relationship between `ActionPlan` and `Metric`. It seems like you want

```
public virtual ICollection<PlanMetric> PlanMetrics { get; set; }
```

instead.

Then, in order to get to an `ActionPlan`'s metrics, you could go through that collection, perhaps through a `Select()`.